# Path to Image stored in document library

Tags: sharepoint-library

Consider the following as my source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Slider Example - Jssor Slider, Carousel, Slideshow</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial, Verdana;background-color:#fff;">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\js\jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\js\jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\js\jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                   
                $DragOrientation: 3                               
            };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        });
    </script>
    <header id="top header">
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
        height: 300px;">        
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <div><img u="image" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\img\1.jpg" /></div>
            <div><img u="image" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\img\2.jpg" /></div>
            <div><img u="image" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\img\3.jpg" /></div>
            <div><img u="image" src="C:\Users\yashs\Desktop\Final Shot\img\4.jpg" /></div>           
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a document library in SharePoint 2010 and stored all js, img and main txt file in this library (All inside the same folder and not in subfolders) I then created a web part (Content Editor) and gave the path to this library. However, this functions well in IE. But in Chrome I cant see the images as well as slider functionality.

Please help. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that will work to add an image and get the right path :

First in your project right click on the sharepoint project then add then sharepoint "layout" mapped folder

this will create a folder for your project inside sharepoint native "Layout" mapped folder

copy/ paste your "images" folder to this folder

in the image src , you can add the path as the following :

"/_layouts/YourProjectFolderName/images/YourImageName"

Deploy The solution and hopefully it will work

Comment: I followed your instructions... Now the images are loaded but still the functionality of slider is not working.... It seems with the help of inspect element that: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/yashs/Desktop/Final%20Shot/js/jssor.js`

Comment: I figured out that we cannot give the path of the local machine since Chrome doesn't allows that due to security reasons. But, I tried to take the path for js files as i did for images, it is opening up a download to save pop-up and not opening this file

Comment: I think the problem is with the loading of the js file as well . You can do the same with your js file by adding your js folder to the mapped project folder inside the layout folder . and add reference to it in your web part like the following :

Comment: <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink1" Name="/_layouts/YourProjectFolderName/js/jssor.js" runat="server">
</SharePoint:ScriptLink>

Comment: and yes you are right in the part that you can not use a path for the local resource . so using this way it is relative and hopefully it will work

Comment: I tried the method mentioned above for the JS files and it is not working

Comment: What error it showed now ?

Comment: "Uncaught Reference Error".... However now the page functioning well even with this error

Comment: So the slider is working now ?

Comment: Slider is working even though I can see an Uncaught Reference Error.